# How can I replace a hamburger menu to a default one in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a built-in default WordPress theme called Scrawl for testing purposes. https://wordpress.org/themes/scrawl/

I was trying to edit the styles but nothing seems working. How can I replace a hamburger menu to a default horizontal navigation menu when viewing in desktop on WordPress? Any information would help!

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 1024px ) and (max-width: 1281px) {


.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-logo {
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation {
    height: 100px;
  }
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation > div,
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .main-navigation {
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    line-height: 2.09231em;
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .main-navigation ul:first-child {
      display: block;
  }
  .main-navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
  .main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .main-navigation ul a {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 14px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 5px 5px 4px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li a,
  .main-navigation ul ul ul li a,
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}
```

Here's my attempt of adding CSS code in the Customizer. I successfully removed the hamburger icon but the links aren't showing up. I didn't see the html structure for the links after I added the code, I was trying to add menus on the menus section but nothing changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it that you are unable to edit the styles at all, or that you need help writing the proper styles?

Comment: I tried to edit the CSS in the customizer, the hamburger icon was gone but the navigation links aren't displaying and I was trying to look for the HTML structure on the inspector and the links wasn't there. Now, I can't seem to find the solution to achieve the horizontal nav menu bar from a hamburger icon.

Comment: Share your attempt at code in the body of the original question.  Then we can probably help you.

Comment: Just updated my post for more additional info.